# Integration of $\sin^2x\sin 3x$

Tags: calculus

Determine $\int \sin^2x\sin 3x dx$.
This is not very hard to do using method of substitution but the solution i have is pretty lengthy,but since this question came in a competitive exam,i was wondering if there was a quick solution.

Comment: Did you use the formula $\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$?

Comment: $\sin^2x = \cfrac{1-\cos2x}{2}$ and $2 \cos2x \sin 3x = \sin 5x + \sin x$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using the formula $$\sin(3x)=3\sin x-4\sin^3x$$ expand the integral and write it in the format of $$3(1-\cos^2x)\sin x-4(1-\cos^2x)^2\sin x$$

Then putting $\cos x=t$ would solve it quite easily

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The standard method for trigonometric polynomials consists in linearising them. More precisely you need here the linearisation formulæ
\begin{align}
\sin^2 x&=\frac{1-\cos 2x}2, \\
\cos a\cos b&=\frac12\bigl(\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)\bigr).
\end{align}